# Compiling QObject-derived class on the command line on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore, moc

I am new to Qt. I am trying to compile a small code snippet shown below:

```
#include<QtCore/QtCore>
#include<QtCore/QObject>

class Test:public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  Test(){qDebug()<<"CTOR";}
};

int main()
{
Test t;
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run it through command line using the following command:

```
g++ -o signalTest.exe -l QtCore signalTest.cpp
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
undefined reference to vtable for Test
```

I think I need to include the library for `QObject`, but I am not really sure. Any ideas?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I tried with your suggestion but its giving wierd errors that too in main.moc file..Is there any library for QObject.

Comment: i have created main.pro as you suggested.I got errors like main.moc:39: error: âTestâ has not been declared
main.moc:48: error: âTestâ has not been declared
main.moc:48: error: non-member function âconst QMetaObject* metaObject()â cannot have cv-qualifier
/usr/include/QtCore/qobject.h: In function âconst QMetaObject* metaObject()â:

Comment: @Laszlo Papp:-- Thank you for help. I have tried with clean environment and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the meta object compiler, aka. moc, properly.

You have a QObject in the source as opposed to the header, so instead of including the header into the `HEADERS` variable for qmake, you will need to include the generated moc file in your source code as demonstrated below.

Please note that you should add the Q_OBJECT macro to your Q_OBJECT in general due to the propeties, signals, and slots that it makes available. This is not strictly necessary to fix this issue, but it is better if you are aware of this.

#### main.cpp

```
#include<QtCore/QtCore>
#include<QtCore/QObject>

class Test:public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  Test(){qDebug()<<"CTOR";}
};

#include "main.moc" // <----- This will make it work

int main()
{
Test t;
return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make
```

Comment: `HEADERS += main.cpp` is missing which instruct qt to run moc tool on this file.

Comment: @MarekR: uh, you should not mix up headers and sources. Also note that, the user was actually using command line rather than qmake. My answer will work with that, too, just fine. In general, HEADERS was not designed for being the primary interface moc. It just comes as an additional convenience. Do not abuse it. :-)

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this is a hack, but it is necessary if you do not have explicit header file for classes where moc tool is needed. Without it your example will not work.

Comment: @MarekR: have you actually tried to run it? It does work, and should work fine. I am afraid you are misunderstanding something.