# in Qt, my class inherit QObject error with "vtable for GameControlCenter", referenced from:

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

The total error message is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "vtable for GameControlCenter", referenced from:
>
> GameControlCenter::GameControlCenter() in gamecontrolcenter.o
>
> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

The head is:

```
#ifndef GAMECONTROLCENTER_H
#define GAMECONTROLCENTER_H

#include "gamewindows.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QPair>
#include <QObject>


class GameControlCenter:public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
GameControlCenter();
```

### QUESTION:

The error become When

> the GameControlCenter inherit QObject and add macro "Q_OBJECT".

Before this opertaion, these code can run normaly.
But I need to add slots function in GameControlCenter head,
so I need to inherit QObject.

### IDE

OS is OS X10.11.2. Qt Creator

Comment: Do a clean build, including running qmake again. If you have mixed in-source and shadow builds, make sure your in-source build is cleaned too (because files there can "override" files in the shadow build directory).

Comment: are you working with Visual Studio?

Comment: I had clean and rebuild the porject but it can not solve problem.

Comment: I'am working in OS X

Comment: Assuming you're dealing with qmake: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595961/qt-a-missing-vtable-usually-means-the-first-non-inline-virtual-member-function). Assuming you're dealing with CMake: turn AUTOMOC on. If it's another build system, state it in the question.

Comment: try manualy qmake, not just rebuild

Comment: Thanks. I found the error code: I had recall this head in other .cpp file. @peppe

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the Q_OBJECT macro is present in the definition of all QObject-derived classes.
- Make sure you declare your QObject-derived classes in your header files only.
- Make sure all of your header files are listed in your .pro file in the HEADERS=    list.
- Run qmake every time you add Q_OBJECT to one of your classes or modify your .pro file

In my code, I repeat call this head file. So if you have the same question, please check your code whether include same file again.